# Laplace transform of inverse error function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, convolution

I want to calculate the convolution of a function with the inverse error function. Therefore I chose to try to first find an integral transform of the inverse error function like the laplace transform:
$$
\int_0^1 \mathrm{erf}^{-1}\left(x\right)\,\exp(-a\,x)\,dx
$$
But cannot solve the integral.